# Issue Installing Talend 7.3, No response

Tags: installation, talend, talend-mdm

I installed `Talend 7.3` and while configuring and opening, it gives no response. I try to click on the `I agree` button but there is no action after clicking and also the page remains same. How can I skip this step and go forward?

It is Windows 10 that I am trying to setup.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. It turnes out that the problem is java version of my computer. I have installed thi right latest version of java and now it works.